# How to restrict a search to multiple sites?

Tags: api, search

Restricting a search to multiple sites - is it possible to do this?

E.g. site:www.google+www.yahoo.com?

Answer (score 3):

Bing does not provide a separate method of specifying which sites to search like Google's annotations.  Instead, you need to add them as parameters in your query string.  To do so, use the OR logical operator along with the site: specification.  Bing prioritizes AND over OR, so make sure you put parentheses around the OR'ed terms.  For example,

```
example search terms (site:google.com OR site:yahoo.com)
```

If you are adding a lot of sites, keep in mind that [the total URL length must be less than 2048 characters, encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334531/what-are-the-query-length-limits-for-the-bing-websearch-api/15445577#15445577).

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` operator and `site:` keyword.

E.g.

```
(site:http://superuser.com/ OR site:http://stackoverflow.com/) (some query)
```

It should work in most of the search engines such as Google, Bing, Yahoo, DuckDuckGo, etc.

> Note: It's important to use capital letters for operators such as `AND` and `OR`, otherwise it could not work.

Answer (score 0):

Format your query like this:

```
site:dell.com OR site:ibm.com "search phrase"
```

So each site/domain with `OR` between. Tested seems to work for both Bing and Google.

Syntax shamelessly taken from [searchenginewatch.com](http://forums.searchenginewatch.com/showthread.php?t=4638).