# Bing News Search API Results

Tags: api, bing

I am working on a custom news widget for a client.  He wants to include news that only has a particular company name as well as one or more industry terms.  For companies [Company A, Company B, Company C], he wants to display aggregated results (newest first) using the following search terms.

```
"Company A" AND ("electric vehicle" OR "PHEV" OR "energy storage" OR "lithium-ion" OR "capacitor" OR "graphite" OR "separators" OR "community energy storage" OR "electricity storage" OR "advanced batteries")

"Company B" AND ("electric vehicle" OR "PHEV" OR "energy storage" OR "lithium-ion" OR "capacitor" OR "graphite" OR "separators" OR "community energy storage" OR "electricity storage" OR "advanced batteries")

"Company C" AND ("electric vehicle" OR "PHEV" OR "energy storage" OR "lithium-ion" OR "capacitor" OR "graphite" OR "separators" OR "community energy storage" OR "electricity storage" OR "advanced batteries")
```

1. I can't find the exact limitations of the Bing News Search API - what are the maximum number of terms?
2. The results that are returned don't necessarily contain the company name.  How can this be explained?

Comment: So, why did you not award the bounty?

Answer (score 2):

**I can't find the exact limitations of the Bing News Search API - what are the maximum number of terms?**

Another question, [What are the query length limits for the Bing WebSearch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334531/what-are-the-query-length-limits-for-the-bing-websearch-api), covers this topic quite thoroughly.  I can't think of any reason that the limits for the News Search API would be any different than for the Web Search API.

**The results that are returned don't necessarily contain the company name. How can this be explained?**

Search engines are not just 'find literal content' searches.  The search engine is not searching its index for pages containing "Company A", but for pages *associated* with Company A, or have much of the same content as Company A's page.  For instance, pages that it links to, or are linked to by pages that also link to Company A, may be returned, even though they don't discuss Company A itself.

You may want to consider reading about Search Engine Optimization (SEO) to learn more about the way search engines work.  The guide at [moz.com](http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/) has a pretty good intro that explains some of the things that make up a search engine.